# How do you apply \Roman to a math expression in a counter?

Tags: counters

Let's say I want to produce the same effect as in [How do you switch numbers in a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623666/how-do-you-switch-numbers-in-a-chapter)

but with Roman numerals. So I would have

- Chapter I
- Chapter II
- Chapter III+IV
- Chapter VI

instead of the arabic version in that post.

In that post, Chapter 3+4 is produced by the following code:

```
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}+\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
```

I wonder if there is a similar way to produce Chapter III+IV. If I just do

```
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}+\Roman{\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}}
```

it will return an error. (The same if I remove `\the`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer really answers the specific question of why the error occurs and how to fix it. It doesn't address the issues answered in the linked question. See egreg's answer for that kind of solution or use the solution here as part of the solution given in the linked question.

The `\Roman` command (and similar commands) expect a counter as an argument, not a number, but your `\numexpr` yields a number, hence the error you receive:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\c@4
```

So if you want to do this simply by using the same method, you need to use the internal command `\@Roman` which expects a number.

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}+\@Roman{\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use the low level command `\@Roman` you can load the `calc` package, and use a temporary counter to achieve the same effect:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{tmpchap}
\usepackage{calc}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\protect\setcounter{tmpchap}{\value{chapter}+1}\Roman{chapter}+\Roman{tmpchap}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks! I find that the plethora of data types in tex always confuses me. There are counters (`chapter`), numbers (`\value`, `\numexpr`), strings (`\Roman{counter}`)...Actually, if I remove `\the` from your code, there will be an error, but I don't understand why. Doesn't \numexpr already return a number? I thought `\the` converts a number to an arabic string.

Comment: @YifengHuang If you want to learn TeX, TeXbook is a good resource. (or TeX by topic.) (or just learn expl3 and ignore the low level details entirely.) `\numexpr` is documented in a different place (etex manual), however.

Comment: @YifengHuang Although I *do not* get an error removing `\the`, so you probably made some mistake somewhere...

Comment: @YifengHuang As noted, the `\the` is not actually needed here, so I've removed it. `\the` is a TeX primitive that does many things, much more than can be explained in a comment, but not surprisingly we have a whole question on it: [The \the command](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674)

Answer (score 4):

Alan Munn’s answer is fine, but there is a better method.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doublechapter}{O{#2}m}
 {
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}
   {
    \int_to_Roman:n {\value{chapter}}+\int_to_Roman:n {\value{chapter}+1}
   }
   \chapter[#1]{#2}
   \stepcounter{chapter}
   \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It is still possible to do `\doublechapter[Short]{Long}`

##### Full example

I use `openany` just to avoid blank pages and `geometry` just to make smaller pictures.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doublechapter}{O{#2}m}
 {
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}
   {
    \int_to_Roman:n {\value{chapter}}+\int_to_Roman:n {\value{chapter}+1}
   }
   \chapter[#1]{#2}
   \stepcounter{chapter}
   \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title one}

\chapter{Title two}

\doublechapter{Title for the double chapter}\label{doublechapter}

\chapter{Title five}

\ref{doublechapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23487/how-can-i-get-roman-numerals-in-text#:%7E:text=You%20can%20convert%20a%20number,counter%3E%7D%20(uppercase).), I found a solution myself.

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman(chapter}+\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax\relax}}
```

To explain according to my understanding, `chapter` is a *counter* (as an argument type), and `\Roman` converts a counter to a string. On the other hand, `\numexpr ... \relax` is a *number*, so we need `\romannumeral...\relax` to convert it to a string. This produces the lower-case Roman numeral, and applying `\uppercase\expandafter{ ... }` makes it upper-case.